# Binding an array property to a form input array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my laravel+vue application I have a computed property that returns an array:

```
selectedIds: function(){
    var ids = this.selected.map(function(currentItem){
        return currentItem.id;
    });
    return ids;
}
```

I am trying to bind this array to my custom input component like this:

```
<myinp type="hidden" name="users[]" :value="selectedIds"></myinp>
```

But when I dump the request array to see the value of `users` input variable, instead of an array of `selectedIds`, I see a single-itemed array of a string of the comma-separated `selectedIds`:

```
"users" => array:1 [▼
   0 => "1,3"
]
```

What I expected to see:

```
"users" => array:2 [▼
   0 => "1",
   1 => "3"
]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: how "users[]" is going to get values?

Comment: From the computed property `selectedIds`?

Comment: So, you can change logic over there and create one array then push new values into that array. at the end return that array only

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing in this:
`selectedIds: function(){
    var ids = this.selected.map(function(currentItem){
        return currentItem.id;
    });
    return ids;
}`

Comment: Yes but using that you'll get values only under single key